# convert primary partitions to logicals without losing data

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, logical-drive

I have 4 partitions on my Hard disc:

1. System reserved - 100 MB -  (Windows 7 create it)
2. C: - 145 GB- (My Windows 7 sp1 installed in it
3. D: -210 GB- (I use It for my softwares)
4. E: -210 GB- (I use it for my multimedia)

my hard disk also have 60 GB unallocated space.
How I can convert D: and E: partitions to logical without losing data and spend huge of time?

Comment: Why don't you just extend D or E and combine the 60GB of unallocated space?  To answer your question, you need to backup the data, beacause any tool you use can cause data loss.

Comment: And since data loss is very much an avoidable horror, I would like to take this opportunity to advocate you should have backed up your data already.

Answer (score 1):

Some commercial Windows tools can do this, as can my open source [FixParts.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) With FixParts, at least, there is one caveat: It requires at least one free sector before each to-be-logical partition. Thus, to convert your D: and E:, you may need to shrink C: and D: with another tool before running FixParts.